# Hibernate inheritance query only for basetype

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping, single-table-inheritance

I have implemented single table inheritance using a Contact class and extended this class in Person class and Company class.

I want to know if there is a way to select Contact instances from the database with the properties defined in Contact class. When I query using "from Contact c" it returns a list of Persons and Company instances not Contact.

Comment: Do you have contacts in your database that are not `Person` or `Company`?

Comment: No, I only save Person and Company in the database, but since they extend Contact I would expect to recieve Contact instances when query from Contact c.

Answer (score 0):

If you have contacts that are not `Person` or `Company` you can use the discriminator column:

```
SELECT cat FROM Contact c WHERE c.class='contact'
```

If you only have `Person` and `Company` instances in your database you should just use a result type of `List<Contact>` and don't care about the specific sub classes. Thats how polymorphism works.

Answer (score 0):

Put polymorphism="explicit" property in base class tag definition